# How do I open different version of IDLE (2.7.6)? linux

Tags: python, linux, python-idle

When I open IDLE it is version 3.4.0. I know that I have Python 2.7.6 installed on my system as well. How can I open the IDLE interface for this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can start python2.7 in a terminal, you should be able to run its version of IDLE by adding option `-m idlelib.idle` to the startup command.  Details depend on your system.

If you can start IDLE with an icon, you should be able to copy the icon and change the python version from 3.6 to 2.7 in the icon properties.  Again, detail depend on your system.

Comment: I am able to open 2.7 in the terminal using the command `python2.7`. There is an icon for 3.4, the command is `/usr/bin/idle-python3.4`. I checked that directory but there is no similar file for 2.7. I tried changing the 3.4 to 2.7 and to 2.7.6 and get "There was an error launching the application" in both cases. I also used the 3.4 startup code and both replaced it with `-m idlelib.idle` and added `-m idlelib.idle` to it, but did not work. Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: If `python2.7` starts 2.7, then `python2.7 -m idlelib.idle` should start IDLE -- if your 2.7 was installed with tkinter and IDLE.  I forgot about the last part.  Some linux distributions make tkinter, IDLE, and turtle a separate, optional, install.  Or, start `python2.7` and at `>>> `, enter `import idlelib.idle`.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! You were right, IDLE for python2.7 was not installed, I did not realize it had to be, I thought it was just a matter of accessing it.